# Unable to get the type of boto3 object

Tags: python, boto3

I want check the type returned by the python boto3 API.

Below is a working code

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'volume-id', 'Values': ['vol-xxx.....']}]) 
volume = list(volumes)[0]
```

printing the value of `volume` variable works

```py
print(volume)

# outputs the following
ec2.Volume(id='xxx....')
```

Print the type says

```py
print(type(volume))

# outputs the following
<class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Volume'>
```

The following code causes error:

```py
if type(volume) == boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Volume:
     print("success")

# Returns AttributeError: module 'boto3.resources.factory' has no attribute 'ec2'
```

The following code doesn't cause exception but the expression evaluates to `False`

```py
print(type(volume) == ec2.Volume)
```

I'm wondering why `print(type(volume))` returns `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Volume` but `type(volume) == boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Volume` fails.

I'm also wondering how to compare the type of variable `volume` as `type(volume) == ec2.Volume` doesn't cause syntax error but is returning `False` (I'm expecting a `True`)

Comment: Having `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Volume` as a string should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
ec2= boto3.resource('ec2') <br>
volume= ec2.Volume('vol-112233445566') <br>

print(volume._ _class_ _) <br> 
print(type(volume))<br>


if volume._ _class_ _== type(volume):<br>
    print('true') <br>
else: <br>
    print('false')<br>
```